# How can I harness a loading gif from a different page?

Tags: jquery, iframe, qlikview

I'd be really grateful for some help to solve this brain teasing problem!

- We have a website which is hosted on one server.
- We also have a web-based application which is hosted on a different server because it uses different technology (QlikView).

What we've done is make the application *look* like it's part of the website by using an iFrame to pull in the application.  The code we've used to do this is shown below:

```
<iframe src="http://www.application_blah.co.uk" width="1190px" height="900px" style="margin: 17px 0 0 -10px; border:none;" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

This works fine.  But the application takes a good 20 seconds to load.  During that time, the user is presented with the header and footer of the website but other than that it's just blank.  There's no sign that anything's happening or that the application's loading.

The application does have a loading gif whilst it's loading if you view it directly rather than through the iFram, but it's positioned at the top right corner of the page, so it's completely out of view of the iFrame.  The loading gif appears in a div with id="InitialLoader".

We don't have control over the code of the application (e.g. to move the loading gif).  But we can edit the code in the website.  I wondered if it would be possible to harness that loading symbol somehow and display our own loading symbol (or indeed the same symbol) as long as that is visible in the application?

One idea I've had is to use jQuery .load, but not sure whether this is feasible?  The loading symbol is not permanently displayed, only when the page is loaded.  I want to display it on our web page when it is being loaded by a specific user.  Here's an example of the code I was thinking of:

**jQuery**

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#loading").load('http://www.application_blah.co.uk #InitialLoader');
});
</script>
```

**Html**

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

I'm very open to suggestions if there are other methods!  It would also be good to know whether the above is feasible?  It's difficult for me to test in the website as I get charged by our agency, so want to be sure before committing!

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: $('#initialLoader img').load(function(){ //execute code to unhide header/footer? });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually try to move the DIV in the frame itself.
The DIV "InitialLoader" is controlled by CSS in Qlikview.
It's possible to edit the CSS to position the DIV at the center of the page.
Then you can edit the "Loading..." text to something else in "opendoc.htm".

Comment: Thanks Rgonomike.  We discovered these files and were able to do it this way.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe the problem you are having is that you are doing the following:

1) You are loading a iframe with a img tag all ready set in it...

2) Asking with jquery if the img has loaded, or applying a onload attribute to it will only fail as the tag has allready been rendered and the DOM does not support this logic it seems.

An option I found is to manually set the source once the document has loaded for the img (if it is possible), the jFiddle gives a quick example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').attr('src', 'http://onerahi.cabu.school.nz/files/2012/09/goes-12-firstimage-large081701.jpg').load(function() { alert('loaded'); });
}
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7E6zQ/

#

Ok so, take the existing image and remake it and add it onto the dom with a new onload function, I think this achieves your result, new fiddle attached.

http://jsfiddle.net/yNGV7/

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var newimg = new Image();
    newimg.src = $('img').attr('src');
    newimg.onload = function() {
         //remove loading msg
        $('.ctx-menu-text').remove();

            //hide the div
        $('#InitialLoader').fadeOut(1000);
    }

    $('img').replaceWith(newimg);
});
```

Comment: Thanks John!  I have responded below - apologies for putting it in the wrong place rather than in this comment bit!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John for your example - it's great to be able to see it on jsfiddle!

From what I understand, you've created some code which displays an alert when the image has finished loading.  Perhaps this can be used for my purposes with a little tweaking?  I'm not sure how.  Here's what I'd need to achieve:

**Whilst application is loading**

Whilst the application is loading, the loading gif container div on www.application-blah.co.uk looks like this:

```
<div id="InitialLoader">
<img src="working.gif">
<span class=ctx-menu-text">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

I would like a loading message to be displayed on www.mysite.com whilst this div is visible on www.application-blah.co.uk.

**Once the application has finished loading**

Once the application has loaded, the style of the div containing the loading gif changes to style="display:none" as below.

```
<div id="InitialLoader" style="display:none">
<img src="working.gif">
<span class=ctx-menu-text">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

I would like the loading message on www.mysite.com to disappear when this happens.

Hope that makes sense!  I know it's not an ideal scenario!

Thanks again!

Katie

Comment: Please see my updated answer (sorry My stack overflow is blocked from home due to ISP fault, so was unable to review over weekend).